# matplotlib: jpg image special effect/transformation as if its on a page of an open book

Tags: image, python-2.7, matplotlib

I wish to appear a figure (and certain text) as if they are printed on a page of an open book. Is it possible to transform an jpg image programmatically or in matplotlib to have such an effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a background axis along with an open source book [image](http://inspirationhut.net/design-resources/38-fantastic-vintage-old-clean-and-free-paper-textures/) to do something like this,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.3]) 

#Plot page from a book
im = plt.imread("./book_page.jpg")
implot = ax1.imshow(im, origin='lower')

# Plot a graph and set background to transparent
x = np.linspace(0,4.*np.pi,40)
y = np.sin(x)
ax2.plot(x,y,'-ro',alpha=0.5)
ax2.set_ylim([-1.1,1.1])
ax2.patch.set_alpha(0.0)

from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
margin = im.shape[0]*0.075
ytext = im.shape[1]/2.+10
ax1.text(margin, ytext, "The following text is an example")
ax1.text(margin, 90, "Figure 1. Showing a sine function")

plt.show()
```

Which looks like this,

[image]

where I used the following book [image](http://i2.wp.com/inspirationhut.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Grunge-Open-Book-Paper-Texture.jpg?resize=700%2C559).

UPDATE: Added non-affine transformation based on scikit-image warp [example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_piecewise_affine.html), but with Maxwell distribution. The solution saves the matplotlib line as an image in order to apply a pointwise transform. Mapping for vector graphics may be possible but I think this will be more complicated...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def maxwellian_transform_image(image):

    from skimage.transform import PiecewiseAffineTransform, warp

    rows, cols = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]

    src_cols = np.linspace(0, cols, 20)
    src_rows = np.linspace(0, rows, 10)
    src_rows, src_cols = np.meshgrid(src_rows, src_cols)
    src = np.dstack([src_cols.flat, src_rows.flat])[0]

    # add maxwellian to row coordinates
    x = np.linspace(0, 3., src.shape[0])
    dst_rows = src[:, 1] + (np.sqrt(2/np.pi)*x**2 * np.exp(-x**2/2)) * 50
    dst_cols = src[:, 0]
    dst_rows *= 1.5
    dst_rows -= 1.0 * 50
    dst = np.vstack([dst_cols, dst_rows]).T

    tform = PiecewiseAffineTransform()
    tform.estimate(src, dst)

    out_rows = image.shape[0] - 1.5 * 50
    out_cols = cols
    out = warp(image, tform, output_shape=(out_rows, out_cols))

    return out

#Create the new figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

#Plot page from a book
im = plt.imread("./book_page.jpg")
implot = ax.imshow(im, origin='lower')

# Plot and save graph as image, will need some manipulation of location
temp, at = plt.subplots()
margin = im.shape[0]*0.1
x = np.linspace(margin,im.shape[0]/2.,40)
y = im.shape[1]/3. + 0.1*im.shape[1]*np.sin(12.*np.pi*x/im.shape[0])
at.plot(x,y,'-ro',alpha=0.5)
temp.savefig("lineplot.png",transparent=True)

#Read in plot as an image and apply transform
plot = plt.imread("./lineplot.png")
out = maxwellian_transform_image(plot)
ax.imshow(out, extent=[0,im.shape[1],0,im.shape[0]])

plt.show()
```

The figure now looks like,

[image]

Comment: @Smith, Thanks for the answer, this is closer, but what I am struggling at is - having a curvy shape to the figure. Lets say, If I define the curved page as having a functional form similar to the maxwellian function, I want to scale/transform my image to follow that curve, so that in it will appear as if its printed on an open curvy page.

Comment: What you are talking about is an affine transformation, for example, http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_piecewise_affine.html. I've updated my answer accordingly, although I'm not sure what you are asking is trivial

Comment: Thanks Ed Smith, this is exactly what I was looking for. This helped. Based on this now I can construct the transform I want to have.